# Why I cannot get the value by binding inside the hiddenfield

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a hiddenfield inside the datagrid. There is a condition to assign the value by binding. However all value on the hiddenfield is blank. I added other column using the same binding that I can get the correct value. Would someone help me how to do it for hiddenfield. Thanks in advance.

This is my code in aspx:

```
<asp:templatecolumn headertext="ok" HeaderStyle-Width="11%" Itemstyle-wrap="False" Visible="true">
                                        <itemtemplate>                                          
                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdNC" Value='<%#IIf(Eval("order") Is DBNull.Value, " ", Eval("order"))%>' 
                                             Visible="true" runat="server"/>
                                        </itemtemplate>
                                </asp:templatecolumn>
```

The following code can show the value in correct:

```
<asp:templatecolumn headertext="order Link" HeaderStyle-Width="11%" Itemstyle-wrap="true" Visible="false">
                                        <itemtemplate>                                                                          
                                                <%#IIf(Eval("order") Is DBNull.Value, " ", Eval("order"))%>                                  
                                        </itemtemplate>

                                </asp:templatecolumn>
```

I want to use the hiddenfield, can someone show me how to binding with condition.

Comment: How are you getting your value  in code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a normal if statement? I think  the IIF function is biting you.Use a normal if statement which will give you the desired result.

```
<asp:templatecolumn headertext="ok" HeaderStyle-Width="11%" Itemstyle-wrap="False" Visible="true">
                                    <itemtemplate>                                          
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdNC" Value='<%#If(Eval("order") Is DBNull.Value, " ", Eval("order"))%>' 
                                         Visible="true" runat="server"/>
                                    </itemtemplate>
                            </asp:templatecolumn>
```

Comment: I need check the data to assign the value into hiddenfield, so I use IIF

Comment: An If statement  will also do that check you are doing with IIF.

Comment: Even I copy your code, it still doesn't work. I think my binding has problem. Even I use the below code, I still cannot get the value       
                                    <itemtemplate>        
                                                                    
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdNC" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Delivery_Date")%>' 
                                         Visible="true" runat="server"/>
                                    </itemtemplate>

Comment: I found it. If I use textbox, the data will show. Even I set the visible on hiddedfield, it is still invisible on datagrid.My code is no problem. Thanks for your help